# Android Espresso Turn OFF Cellular Data on Android Emulator through Runtime() not working

Tags: android-testing, android-instrumentation

I am writing instrumentation test for a scenario where data is not available on android emulator (api 16 and api 23). I tried the following code to disable data,

```
@Test
public void disconnectData() throws IOException {
    String line;

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("svc data disable");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        Log.d("asdf", line);
    }

    in.close();
}
```

It does not do anything. Data is not disabled. It simply passed without error. There is no output.

If I run the same command from terminal using adb, it works:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell
svc data disable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution is to use mockwebserver. E.g.,

```
   server.enqueue(new MockResponse()
            .setResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR)
            .setBody(getStringFromFile(getInstrumentation().getContext(), "login.json")));
```